# File uploading working manually but not through program

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-classic

My upload of csv file goes in this way, there is a text box where file path can be loaded through the browser button subsequently I would press the upload button, Now my problem reside here, While I try to do the aforementioned process through manually it's workign fine, but what happens is, when I try to do through programmetically, It's clearing the text field at the time of clicking the upload button consequently empty is taken from text field while uploading, so it's not uploading anything.

My piece of code :

```
$browser.file_field(:id,"additionalInfo(clientUri)").click_no_wait
      sleep 2
      save_dialog = WIN32OLE.new("AutoItX3.Control")
      save_dialog.ControlSend("Choose File to Upload", "", "Edit1", sMEPackageData['MachineryUploadPath'])
      sleep 2
      saveClick=save_dialog.ControlClick("Choose File to Upload","", "&Open")
      sleep 2
```

ruby 1.8.7,watir 3.0.0
Can anyone please help me on this ?

Comment: Is there a reason why you do not use the built-in `FileField#set` method?

Comment: No reasons. Can you please elaborate on the above method ?

Answer (score 0):

Watir provides a method for uploading files to file fields - [`FileField#set`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir-classic/Watir/FileField#set-instance_method).

You simply pass the path of your file to the `set` method:

```
 $browser.file_field(:id,"additionalInfo(clientUri)").set(sMEPackageData['MachineryUploadPath'])
```

Comment: infact on testing again,it does the same thing as i mentioned in the question.

Comment: I think you need to give more details on how to reproduce the problem. A page that reproduces that same issue would really help. Adding the full exception would also help.

Comment: Through your set of code its reproducing the same issue again i.e. It's clearing the text field at the time of clicking the upload button consequently empty is taken from text field while uploading

Comment: What version of IE are you using? Does the problem happen with every file field you interact with or just those in your application?

Comment: I am using IE 10. When i try to add the csv file using ie 10, I am facing this issue manually it's working fine in ie10. Not with every field only with this field .

Comment: i am not able to post images since i dont have 10 reputation as the error says in stackoverflow.